# How can I access data from outside the app class in appdesigner (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have created a very simple GUI in appdesigner (Matlab) with one dropdown menu. Additionally, I took the code that got generated (under 'Code View' tab) and pasted that in a normal .m file (because, I want to further add some more contents to this code). My question is how can I access certain variable from this self generated code, so that I can play with that value outside of the main class?

For example:

In App class, for this dropdown menu section, following line of code got generated:

```
app.ColorDropDown = uidropdown(app.UIFigure);
app.ColorDropDown.Items = {'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'};
app.ColorDropDown.Position = [277 178 140 22];
app.ColorDropDown.Value = 'Red';
```

**Outside of this app class:** Depending upon the value that was selected in this dropdown menu, I want to capture that in a normal variable, and show some other results based on the color selected

Thanks

Comment: You aren't supposed to copy/paste the code outside of the code editor with App Designer. If you want to add your own code, you should add a new function to your class using the "Function" button in App Designer. The app can also call any other matlab function so you could just pass the information from the app to another function by calling it inside the App Designer code.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a good answer because it's not entirely clear what is the UX you're trying to achieve. In general - the best way is to create an [event listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html). The "quick and dirty" way is to use `setappdata`/`getappdata`. The last resort is a `global` variable.

Comment: @Ajeya Gupta You're welcome.

Comment: It is unclear if you're trying to listen for the change or simply get the color into the base workspace. If the latter, then you could use [assignin()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) in your dropdown callback funciton. Though I wouldn't use that for a production solution.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the essence of your question is about sharing data between GUIs as you state you want to "show some other results based on the color selected".

Note: **[MATLAB documentation cautions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figureappd-properties.html#expand_panel_heading_bu4i700-1_sep_shared-UserData):** *Do not use `UserData` property in apps you create with App Designer*.

The documentation goes on to recommend approaches for [sharing data among app designer apps](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-across-callbacks-in-app-designer.html) and [creating multiwindow apps in app designer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/creating-multiwindow-apps-in-app-designer.html).

For the sake of completeness, I'll provide a detailed example, different from the MATLAB documentation, of how this can be accomplished entirely within the App Designer.

## Setup

I created 2 app designer apps, **controlGUI.mlapp** and **plotGUI.mlapp**. Running `controlGUI()` loads both mlapp files at once and then allows you to control aspects of the plotGUI from callbacks in the controlGUI. Of course, the plotGUI could do anything but I have it changing visual aspects of the plotted data.

[image]

## Details

For simplicity, I am setting the controlGUI be the main application. I can do this be adding a property in controlGUI named `PlotWindow` and having it contain the output of calling `plotGUI()`; the other mlapp. I also have a callback function I recycle for the three dropdowns that updates a DATA property in the plotGUI. This DATA property has a listener attached that fires a callback to update the `uiaxes` object.

### The plotGUI

The magic is really in this object. That is, I created a property named DATA and altered the access. By setting the property access `SetObservable = true`, we can then add a `PostSet` event listener, which I stored in a private property called `dataChangedListener` during the `startupFcn`.

```matlab
properties (Access = public, SetObservable=true)
    DATA % A struct with xdata, ydata, fields. Other line prop fields ok
end

properties (Access = private)
    dataChangedListener % listener object for when DATA is changed.
end
```

Then the startup function, `startupFcn`, initializes the DATA property with some (arbitrary) data as struct *then* adds and enables the `PostSet` listener.

```matlab
% Code that executes after component creation
    function startupFcn(app, data)
        if nargin < 2
            % create a default dataset
            data = struct();
            data.xdata = linspace(0,1,1001);
            data.ydata = sin(data.xdata.*2*pi*10);%10hz signal
            data.color = app.Axes.ColorOrder(1,:);
        end
        app.DATA = data;
        % plot the data
        line(data, 'parent', app.Axes);

        % add and enable PostSet event listener for the DATA property
        app.dataChangedListener = addlistener(...
            app,'DATA','PostSet', ...
            @(s,e) app.updatePlot ...
            );
        app.dataChangedListener.Enabled = true;
    end
```

The `PostSet` listener calls the method `app.updatePlot()`, so we have to add this method to our app. This method will get called **whenever anything in `app.DATA` gets modified**. So I created the "function" (as the Code Browser calls it) which simply deletes the `axes` children (the existing line) and uses the *low-level* version of `line()` to draw a [primitive line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html) based on the `app.DATA` struct object:

```matlab
function updatePlot(app)
        %clear plot
        delete(app.Axes.Children);
        % draw the new plot
        line(app.DATA, 'parent', app.Axes);
    end
```

Yes, `line()` will accept a struct which has field names that correspond to valid line properties but I can't seem to find the reference specifically. But if you read about the [inputParser object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html#expand_panel_heading_d119e578919)... sorry, getting off topic.

### The controlGUI

This object is simpler. It holds the plotGUI in a property, allowing direct access to the plotGUI properties and public methods.

```matlab
properties (Access = public)
    PlotWindow = plotGUI() % holds the reference to the plot window
end
```

I also created an `updatePlot` callback method here, different from the plotGUI method, bad naming on my part. Nonetheless, this control method takes the values from controlGUI dropdowns and then modifies the plotGUI `DATA` struct, stored in `app.PlotWindow.DATA`. So this one callback is called whenever any of the dropdowns are changed (`ValueChangedFcn`). Consequently, the `PostSet` listener for the `DATA` struct will fire the callback to update the plot accordingly.

```matlab
% Value changed function: LineColor, LineStyle, MarkerStyle
    function updatePlot(app, event)
        mStyle= app.MarkerStyle.Value;
        lStyle= app.LineStyle.Value;
        lColor = app.LineColor.Value;
        d = app.PlotWindow.DATA;
        switch mStyle
            case 'none'
                d.marker = 'none';
            case 'circle'
                d.marker = 'o';
            case 'diamond'
                d.marker = 'diamond';
            case 'point'
                d.marker = '.';
        end
        switch lStyle
            case 'none'                    
                d.linestyle = 'none';
            case 'solid'
                d.linestyle = '-';
            case 'dashed'
                d.linestyle = '--';
            case 'dotted'
                d.linestyle = ':';
        end
        d.color = lColor;
        % set the data back into the plotGUI
        % The plotGUI's DATA PostSet listener will update the actual plot
        app.PlotWindow.DATA = d;
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to copy/paste the code outside of the code editor with App Designer. If you want to add your own code, you should add a new function to your class using the "Function" button in App Designer. The app can also call any other matlab function so you could just pass the information from the app to another function by calling it inside the App Designer code

For example see this example from a demo I created. It uses a drop down `ChartTypeDropDown` to determine what type of chart it should draw. I added a new `function` called `DrawChart` which uses the data from the GUI to draw a graph depending on the values selected/entered in to the various boxes.

```
    function results = DrawChart(app)
        chartType = app.ChartTypeDropDown.Value;
        chartTime = app.TimeEditField.Value;
        chartA = app.AEditField.Value;
        chartB = app.BEditField.Value;
        chartC = app.CEditField.Value;
        t = [0:0.1:chartTime];
        if strcmp(chartType,'Sin')
            y = chartA * sin(chartB*t)+chartC;
        elseif strcmp(chartType,'Cos')
            y = chartA * cos(chartB*t)+chartC;
        elseif strcmp(chartType,'Exp')
            y = exp(t);
        else
            y = x;
        end
        ax = app.UIAxes;
        ax.Title.String = chartType;
        plot(ax,t,y);
    end
```

This function is called by the callback linked to a button

```
    function DrawButtonPushed(app, event)
        DrawChart(app);
    end
```

Note how I call regular matlab functions such as sin/cos/exp. These could just as easily be a Matlab function that you have written.