# How to implement a modal pop-up window on an app (mlapp)?

Tags: matlab-app-designer

I want to create a modal popup window, containing a number of uiedit, uimenu and uipushbutton controls. This modal popup window should appear on top of a MATLAB app (built with the app designer; not with GUIDE). The parent app UIFigure should be grayed out while the modal popup is active, similar to what happens when a [uiconfirm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiconfirm.html) dialog box is opened. Is there an undocumented way or some other workaround to implement this type of UI element?

The idea is that the user clicks on a "settings" button on the main app and the modal dialog pops up, while deactivating the main app controls, to allow adjustment of settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for [uiwait](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html) which explains exactly how to achieve your desired effect.

In the interest of adhering to best practices for providing meaningful answers, I might approach this problem as follows.

Create a callback for the "settings" button which:

- "grays out" desired *main* app's UI elements by setting their `Enable` property to `'off'`
- instantiates the *.mlapp you've created for the settings UI

From here, there are a number of possibilities. One approach would be to `uiwait` on the settings mlapp's **UIFigure** since, by default, it is contained in a public property of the mlapp definition. If you want to wait until the settings UI is closed, you can get away with, simply, `uiwait(settingsApp.UIFigure);`. Once the settings UI is closed, you can re-enable all your main app components to un-"gray" them.

For example, your "Settings button" callback could look like:

```matlab
function onRequestSettings(app, event)
  % set main figure's UI elements gray
  % Assuming you want all elements gray
  set(app.UIFigure.Children, 'Enable', 'off');

  % create the settings UI by instantiating it here
  settingsApp = settingsUI();

  % wait until the figure closes
  uiwait(settingsApp.UIFigure);

  % ... SEE NOTE BELOW CODE BLOCK! ... %

  % Now that the settings UI is closed,
  % set main figure's UI elements back to normal.
  % Again, assuming all elements here
  set(app.UIFigure.Children, 'Enable', 'on');
end
```

#### Note:

While the above code block will produce your desired behavior, I have not shown how to share the data between the settings app and the main app. 
I assume, since you do not explicitly ask for this, that you have some way in mind. If not, I will point you to the documentation for [creating multi-window apps](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/creating-multiwindow-apps-in-app-designer.html) and [sharing data within app designer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-across-callbacks-in-app-designer.html) and also to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084715/6061739). Alternatively, you can leverage the fact that mlapps are members of the `handle` super-class and thus have a builtin event, [`ObjectBeingDestroyed`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html#mw_c598e006-ccaf-4a3d-adcc-42126061c400). You can construct a listener (see [`addlistener`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html)) for this event and bind it to a method in your main app which then updates the main app according to changes made on the settings app.

#### Alternatively:

If the settingsUI is stored in a property of the main app, say `app.settingsUI`, and is instantiated, but perhaps hidden, by the main app's `startupFcn`, then instead of re-instantiating every time the "Settings button" is pressed you could simply bring it forward with `figure(app.settingsUI.UIFigure);`. Then make it "modal" with `uiwait(app.settingsUI.UIFigure);` and override the settingsUI `closeRequestFcn` to release the code execution halt with `uiresume`. The close callback could look like:

```matlab
classdef settingsUI < matlab.apps.AppBase

...

  function UIFigureCloseRequest(app,event)
    % override close request to prevent deleting the app
    % hide the settings window to appear as though it was closed
    app.UIFigure.Visible = 'off';

    % resume code execution so that main app can continue to run.
    uiresume(app.UIFigure);
  end

...

end
```

-Cheers